# Strip GUID from field if present

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

MY client webservice returning some field with GUID and some not.
I want to write a function which will check if there is GUID in that field i need to strip off that GUID from that, If GUID not present then return field as it is.

Prototype of function:-

```
function stripGuid(field)
{
 //check if field has GUID then strip off, return new strip field
 //else return field as it is
 }
```

Sample data:-

```
 4922093F-148F-4220-B321-0FBB1843B5DDrec_guid   
 4922093F-148F-4220-B321-0FBB1843B5DDdate_add
 tablenam
 sessguid
```

How I call function:-

```
stripGuid(sampleData);
```

Expected Output:-

```
 rec_guid
 date_add
 tablenam
 sessguid
```

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Sorry forgot to add expected output. Now added in question.

Comment: But 2nd line has `date_add` in input and `date_guid` in output

Comment: Ya, It's my mistake. It's just an typo error. Now fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As with most things regex, the complexity of the answer depends on how many cases you need to cover, for example:

```
return field.replace(/[0-9a-fA-F\-]{36}/g, "");
```

will cover most cases and isn't too terrible to read, but it fails in some pretty important cases, so it might be that

```
return field.replace(/[0-9a-fA-F]{8}\-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-?[0-9a-fA-F]{4}\-?[0-9a-fA-F]{12}/g, "");
```

would work better for you (as it ensures that the dashes are all in the right place, and that there are the right number of them).  The better option depends on how standardized you expect the input to be and where your project draws the line between readability and correctness.  Without more details it's hard to say what would be best for you.

Edit:  Nate Kerkhofs is right, I had left off the global flag on the above regexes, it's fixed now.

Comment: But what will happen when my sample data have '-', Then it will works? Sorry but I don't know anything about REGX, That's why i am asking.

Comment: Is this possible can we add a flag in returned string if GUID is present or not.

Comment: The first of those regexes will only work when the dashes are there, the second one will work with or without dashes.  Both of them work for either upper or lower case.  If you want to put in a flag in place of the guid, simply put the flag text in the second argument of replace instead of the empty string.

Comment: No i want both flag and guid, Can i append something in GUID? Is this right way to get GUID with flag in return?

Comment: I'm confused, for the inputs in the question, what outputs do you want?

Comment: That is my first requirement. And with your help it's working. Now i want a another function which checks GUID is present or not in field.

Comment: Ah, I see, in that case you can use [match](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_match.asp) with the same regex from above, that will tell you if there is a match without modifying anything.

Answer (score 1):

```
return field.replace(/[a-f0-9]{8}-(?:[a-f0-9]{4}-){3}[a-f0-9]{12}/gi, "");
```

Unlike teryret's solution, this removes all guids, and also ignores case for easier reading.